# Найти наиболее часто встречающуюся пару значений Python Pandas

Tags: python, алгоритм, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть следующий DataFrame:

```
Транзакция  Сумма   Товар
1   500 1
1   600 2
1   500 1
1   548 3
1   849 1
2   654 4
2   654 1
2   321 2
2   469 2
2   465 5
3   564 1
3   465 6
3   444 7
3   123 6
3   648 7
```

Необходимо найти пару самых часто встречающихся товаров в каждой транзакции и указать количество этих транзакции.
В данном примере ответ должен быть товар 1 , 2 , встретился в 2 транзакциях

Answer (score 2):

Векторизированные Pandas / Numpy решения в вашем случае будут сильно уступать по скорости обработки специализированным библиотекам, которые реализуют ["Apriori" алгоритм](https://loginom.ru/blog/apriori) и ему подобные.

Ссылки на модули:

- [efficient-apriori](https://pypi.org/project/efficient-apriori/)
- [FP-growth](https://borgelt.net/doc/fpgrowth/fpgrowth.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать группировкой (если я понял вопрос правильно):

```
res = df.groupby("Товар", as_index=False)["Транзакция"].nunique().sort_values("Транзакция", ascending=False).head(2)["Товар"].tolist()
```

res:

```
[1, 2]
```